# Results from query where 2 date ranges intersect

Tags: php, date, range

So im gonna try to explain this:

I got datepicker where you select 2 dates (start and end).

For example:
01-01-2012 till 11-12-2012

Now im gonna use these dates to search for jobs in a table:

startdate job: 10-10-2012
enddate job: 20-12-2012

I want to get that job as a result, because the job is running between those 2 dates.

I tried to use BETWEEN but that doesn't seem to work for me. Can somebody help me with the query? Ofcourse i translate the date format to yyyy-mm-dd.

The point is that i want to show the job even if only 1 day is in the range of the datepicker date.

Comment: mySQL expects the date format to be `YYYY-MM-DD` for a `DATE` or `DATETIME` field. That is probably why it doesn't work. YOur date picker might have a formatting option

Comment: Ofcourse i format the dates to yyyy-mm-dd. Still i get only results when the daterange is IN the daterange from the datepicker. The point is that i want to show the job even if only 1 day is in the range of the datepicker date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the intersection of 2 date ranges.  So given dateranges d1 and d2, you know that d2.start must occur before d1.end.  You also know that d2.end must occur after d1.start. If both conditions are true, then you have overlap.  In SQL:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM thedates d
WHERE d.jobstart < $myenddate
  AND d.jobend > $mystartdate
```

ETA diagram for clarity:

[image]

Comment: I just tried this and its perfect, i get the exact results that i want! Its so simple, but proberly i didnt think simple enough..Thanks!

Comment: @Kenny: glad it was useful.  I've added a diagram that illustrates the reasoning. Drawing it out helped a lot back when I first started comparing ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the statement as

```
SELECT * FROM dummydb.tblorders t where t.date_purchased >= '2012-03-24 00:00:00' and t.date_purchased <= '2012-03-24 23:59:59';
```

Comment: No that wont work, because the range of the JOB can also be outside of the range from the datepicker. The point is that i want to show the job even if only 1 day is in the range of the datepicker date.

Comment: If you are using the datepicker for me thats javascript if your asking for getting value between two dates this is MySql Solution.

Comment: This has nothing todo with the datepicker. The dates are saved and formatted to yyyy-mm-dd when used for SQL. I'm not asking how to format dates :)

Comment: use count in this case and save it to some variable and check if count is greater than one then dont show set @variable = SELECT count(*) FROM dummydb.tblorders t where t.date_purchased >= '2012-03-24 00:00:00' and t.date_purchased <= '2012-03-24 23:59:59';

Comment: Thanks for your help but im going with the solution dnagirl gave me.